# Error Loading AJAX on Document Ready Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a PHP page that periodically updates values of several elements on the page. I'm using a host that limits my hits per day, and each hit to any page they're hosting for me counts against my total. Therefore, I'm trying to use JQuery/AJAX to load all of the information that I need from other pages at one time.

I'm calling the following index.php. This method achieves the desired affect exactly the way I want it, but results in three hits (dating.php, dgperc.php, and pkperc.php) every two seconds:

```js
var focused = true;
$(window).blur(function() {
    focused = false;
});
$(window).focus(function() {
    focused = true;
});
function loadData() {
    if (focused) {
         var php = ["dating", "dgperc", "pkperc"];
         $.each(php, function(index, value) {
             $('#'+this).load(this+'.php');
         });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadData();
});
setInterval(function() {
    loadData();
}, 2000);
```

I'm calling the following index1.php. This is where I'm at as far as a method that only results in one hit every two seconds. My workaround is that I have combined the three php pages that I was loading into one, dating1.php. I load this into a div element, #cache, all at once. This element is set to hidden using CSS, and then I just copy its inner HTML into the appropriate elements:

```js
var focused = true;
$(window).blur(function() {
    focused = false;
});
$(window).focus(function() {
    focused = true;
});
function loadData() {
    if (focused) {
        var php = ["dating", "dgperc", "pkperc"];
        $('#cache').load('dating1.php');
        $.each(php, function(index, value) {
            $('#'+this+'1').html($('#'+this).html());
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadData();
});
setInterval(function() {
    loadData();
}, 2000);
```

Dating1.php will produce different outputs every time it's run, but here is an example of the output:

```html
<span id = "dating">4 years, 7 months, 3 weeks, 10 seconds ago.</span>
<span id = "dgperc">21.9229663059</span>
<span id = "pkperc">22.2121099923</span>
```

On document ready, index1.php does not function properly: the #cache element isn't filled at all, so the other elements don't get filled either. However, after two seconds, the loadData() function runs again, and then the #cache element is filled correctly, and so are the other elements. For some reason, this isn't a problem on my index.php page at all, and I'm not sure why there's a difference here.

How can I get #cache to load the first time so that the page loads correctly? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each AJAX call is basically a page visit in the background.  Like telling your assistant three different times to get you one coffee.  Or telling them one to get you three coffees.

If you don't want to combine your three PHP pages into one - thus keeping code separate and easier to maintain.  Consider creating one "cache.php" script and inside it:

```
cache.php:

$outputData = array('dating' => false, 'dgperc' => false, 'pkperc' => false);

foreach($outputData as $file => &$data)
{
    //buffer output
    ob_start();

    //run first script (be smart and file_exists() first)
    include_once($file . '.php');

    $data = ob_get_clean();
}

//output JSON-compliant for easy jQuery consumption
echo json_encode($outputData);
```

Then in your javascript:

```
function loadData() {
    if (focused) {
        //call ajax with json and fill your spans
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                $('#dating').html(data.dating);
                $('#dgperc').html(data.dgperc);
                $('#pkperc').html(data.dgperc);

                // NOTE... do a console.dir(data) to get the correct notation for your returned data
            },
            url: 'cache.php'
        });
}
```

You are calling `cache.php` once every two seconds, saving on the 3-hits of calling the php files individually.  Using a middle-man file you keep your scripts separate for maintainability.